# wordpress multiple taxonomy lists

Tags: php, wordpress, drop-down-menu, taxonomy

Hi everyone there is a small plugin called

> Drop-down-custom-taxonomy

but it searches one parameter at a time example link on my test http://sibzal.ru/ 
is there any way to make it's searches sequential/simultanious like i collect all needed parameters and then `submit` like here http://mchome.com.mx/propiedades/ them to query
or how and where i should insert `relation => AND`
here is the plugin code

```
`

function the_dropdown_taxonomy($taxonomy) {
  $id = "{$taxonomy}-dropdown";
  $js =<<<SCRIPT
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $("select#{$id}").change(function(){
    window.location.href = $(this).val();
  });
 });
</script>
SCRIPT;
  echo $js;
  $terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
  echo "<select name=\"{$id}\" id=\"{$id}\">";
  echo '<option value="#"> - Выбрать - </option>';
  foreach($terms as $term) {
    echo '<option value="';
    echo get_term_link(intval($term->term_id),$taxonomy);
    echo '">' . "{$term->name}</option>";
  }
  echo "</select>";
  }

add_action('init','jquery_init');
function jquery_init() {
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
?>
`
```

and this is my current display code

```
`

<div id="browselist" class="clearfix">
<h3 class="sidetitle"> Подобрать помещение</h3>
<p class="listin"><span>Город</span><br/><?php the_dropdown_taxonomy('city'); ?></p>
<p class="listin"><span>Район</span><br/><?php the_dropdown_taxonomy('location'); ?></p>
<p class="listir"><span>Тип помещения</span><br/><?php the_dropdown_taxonomy('property'); ?></p>
<p class="listin"><span>Площадь в м2</span><br/><?php the_dropdown_taxonomy('area'); ?></p>
<p class="listir"><span>Вместимость (чел.)</span><br/><?php the_dropdown_taxonomy('capacity'); ?></p>
<p class="listir"><span>Ценовой диапазон</span><br/><?php the_dropdown_taxonomy('range'); ?></p>
</div>
`
```